# java:enlisting .zip file from a directory

Tags: java, xml, zip

I have a folder containing a large number of `.zip` files. I would like to enlist 
those file and recursively read the compressed `.xml` files. How would i first enlist those `.zip` files?I didn't get any idea at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `File` object for your directory and call its `listFiles`method with an appropriate filter for your zip Files.

Construct a `ZipFile` object for every zipfile and call its `entries()` method to get a list of entries. Find the `ZipEntry` of the sought XML file and call `ZipFile.getInputstream(xmlZipFileEntry)` to start reading its content.